# Trouble calculating time difference in PHP when doing action

Tags: php, time, datediff

```
$timeFromMysql = strtotime($createdtime);
$currenTime = SPRequest::now();;

if ($diff = abs( strtotime( $timeFromMysql ) - strtotime( $currenTime )  > 30*24*60*60) {  
  ACTION
}
```

I just wondering if I am doing this right. it seems the action is done wihout the time check.

Comment: Is `currenTime` a typo?

Comment: @JoeFrambach It's the same in both places ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your parens don't match.

```
if ($diff = abs( strtotime( $timeFromMysql ) - strtotime( $currenTime ) )  > 30*24*60*60) {  
 //ACTION
}
```

To break it down further:

```
if (
  $diff = abs(
    strtotime( $timeFromMysql ) - strtotime( $currenTime )
  )  > 30*24*60*60)
{  
 //ACTION
}
```

Count your parentheses and make sure they're matched.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check if equals - you assign the value to $diff, which is always true. So:

```
$diff ==
```

Comment: No I think OP wants to store the time diff in the variable `$diff`, then check it against `30*24*60*60`.

Comment: yes that's what I want. In the database there is a date (&createdtime). This was the time the api set info into the database. After a month I want to update no sooner. So the difference between the current and the database time should be checked.  But where did I miss some code?

Answer (score 0):

I get the following error:

PHP Notice:  Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int blabla in rule 128

this is the code (128):

```
if ( $difference > 30*24*60*60) {
```

for more information here is a bigger code:

```
$timeFromMysql = strtotime($createdtime);
$currenTime = SPRequest::now();

function format_interval(DateInterval $interval) {
    $result = "";
    if ($interval->y) { $result .= $interval->format("%y years "); }
    if ($interval->m) { $result .= $interval->format("%m months "); }
    if ($interval->d) { $result .= $interval->format("%d days "); }
    if ($interval->h) { $result .= $interval->format("%h hours "); }
    if ($interval->i) { $result .= $interval->format("%i minutes "); }
    if ($interval->s) { $result .= $interval->format("%s seconds "); }
    return $result;
}

$first_date = new DateTime($createdtime);
$second_date = new DateTime($currenTime);

$difference = $first_date->diff($second_date);

//echo format_interval($difference);
//echo $createdtime;
//echo $currenTime;

if ( $difference > 30*24*60*60) { 
    // load the apicall
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($api);
}
```

echos works fine.